# Console Application in C# to ASP.NET difficulties

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am in the process of creating an ASP.NET application from a previous console application that I had created.  I am having problems while trying to do this.  The console application is a calculator to find the monthly payment for a loan. I am stuck on how to get the MonthlyPayment calculation to work in the ASP.NET coding.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LoanCalculator
{
    public class LoanCalculator
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // declare variables
            double principle = 0; 
            double years = 0;
            double interest = 0;
            string principleInput, yearsInput, interestInput;


            // User input for Principle amount in dollars
            Console.Write("Enter the loan amount, in dollars(0000.00): ");
            principleInput = Console.ReadLine();
            principle = double.Parse(principleInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (principle < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value for the mortgage cannot be a negative value");
                principle = 0;
            }


            // User input for number of years
            Console.Write("Enter the number of years: ");
            yearsInput = Console.ReadLine();
            years = double.Parse(yearsInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (years < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Years cannot be a negative value");
                years = 0;
            }

            // User input for interest rate
            Console.Write("Enter the interest rate(%): ");
            interestInput = Console.ReadLine();
            interest = double.Parse(interestInput);
            //Prompt the user to reenter any illegal input
            if (interest < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The value for the interest rate cannot be a negative value");
                interest = 0;
            }

            //Calculate the monthly payment
            //ADD IN THE .Net function call Math.pow(x, y) to compute xy (x raised to the y power). 
            double loanM = (interest / 1200.0);
            double numberMonths = years * 12;
            double negNumberMonths = 0 - numberMonths;
            double monthlyPayment = principle * loanM / (1 - System.Math.Pow((1 + loanM), negNumberMonths));

            //double totalPayment = monthlyPayment;


            //Output the result of the monthly payment
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The amount of the monthly payment is: {0}{1:0.00}", "$", monthlyPayment));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to end. . .");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

The page markup code I now have is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Monthly Mortgage Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h1>Monthly Payment Loan Calculator</h1>
    </div>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please enter the principle amount"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrinciple" runat="server" 
        ontextchanged="txtPrinciple_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
        Text="Please enter the loan duration in years"></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblYears" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="rblYears_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="15">15 Years</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="30">30 Years</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Other</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtYears" runat="server" Enabled="False"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Please select the interest rate"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlInterestRate" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Monthly Payment" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server"></asp:Label>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, my current aspx.cs code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //double principle = 0;
    //double years = 0;
    double interest = 0;
    //string principalInput, yearsInput, interestInput;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txtYears.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double principle = 0.0;
        double principleInput = double.Parse(txtPrinciple.Text);

        double years = double.Parse(txtYears.Text);
        var yearDuration = rblYears.SelectedValue;

        double interestInput = double.Parse(ddlInterestRate.SelectedValue);

        if (double.TryParse(txtPrinciple.Text, out principle))
        {

        }
    }

    protected void rblYears_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rblYears.SelectedIndex == 3)
            txtYears.Enabled = true;
        else
        {
            txtYears.Text = "";
            txtYears.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    protected void txtPrinciple_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // principle = double.Parse(txtPrinciple.Text);

    }
}
```

I know this is not complete, I just kind of hit a road bump and am wondering if I am heading into the right direction or not.  If someone can please lead me the right way it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all.

Comment: You've provided a large amount of code, but haven't actually asked a specific question. That means we can't provide a specific answer. What *exactly* are you stuck on?

Comment: @Jon I am having my difficulties getting the calculations to work in the ASP.NET portion and where I would place the MonthlyPayment coding.

Comment: That's still not really specific enough. *What* difficulties are you having getting the calculations to work? Have you done any ASP.NET work before? If not, I'd suggest you start with something else just to get the ideas behind it before you start trying to do "real" work.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to bring your `LoanCalculator` class into your ASP.Net site.

If it's a Web Site rather than Web Application Project, then put it in your `App_Code` folder. Otherwise you can put it where ever you like.

Change it slightly:

Remove `using System.Threading.Tasks;` - it's not needed here.

Also, rather than `public static void Main(string[] args)`

change it to

`public static double MonthlyPayment(string[] args)`

Remove all the `Console.Write` code, and simply `return monthlyPayment;` after you have calculated it.

You can then call it from your page code behind by simply calling:

```
myPaymentLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:C}",LoanCalculator.LoanCalculator.MonthlyPayment(yourArgs));
```

The `String.Format()` part will convert the result into a currency decimal by passing in the format `{0:C}`.

That would be the basics involved in getting your LoanCalculator working.

You can then extend it further of course, such as giving the class Public Properties and changing the `public static decimal MonthlyPayment(string[] args)` to `Public LoanCalculator(string[] args)` - then populating the properties of the class with your results.